# Maven problems with IntelliJ 2020.2

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

lately I tried to use 2020.2 and I have an interesting Problem and I could not find lead in the internet so I like to ask here....

This specific Project does not manage to resolve Maven Dependencies (I have other Maven projects that are perfectly working)....

Below is the Stacktrace for the error,

"2020-09-15 09:27:53,659 [  36193]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Sent token to maven server
2020-09-15 09:27:56,064 [  38598]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon"

Interesting part I have no idea, while other Maven Projects are working and why IntelliJ can't find HttpWagon....

Only interesting thing, this Project uses Eclipse XText which includes Google Guice libraries and I have a feeling from stack trace that they are leaking to the IntelliJ Maven classpath....otherwise I can't explain why HttpWagon class is not findable...

[IDEA.log and pom.xml snippet](https://pastebin.com/j6kc2nim)

Full Exception....

```
    2020-09-15 09:27:53,659 [  36193]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Sent token to maven server 
2020-09-15 09:27:56,064 [  38598]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1070)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:846)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.getProjectBuildingResults(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder$3.run(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:683)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder$2.run(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:347)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithSessionScope(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:344)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.doResolveProject(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:664)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolveProject(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:626)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Does the build work if you use maven nativly?

Comment: Yep, same project works with 2019.3.4 also a colleague told me it also work with 2020.1.3, I have no idea what is the problem with 2020.2...

Comment: Could you please share full idea.log after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: Ok, I placed to original Post, I have to obfuscate somethings otherwise I will get stress with my Project

Comment: Thanks! What Maven version do you use? Is it possible to reproduce the issue with some sample project?

Comment: Unfortunately our Project structure is little bit complex, I can try to reproduce the problem but I am not exactly sure which part is causing the problem. Below I will place the part I think is causing the problem. 'exec-maven' or 'xtext-maven' having their dependencies in plugin dependencies defined causes their classpath to leak to IntelliJ Maven module I think. Maven version is 3.6.3

Comment: Unfortunately Admins deleted my answers, the Texts are bigger then 30000 Charaters and Stackoverflow does not let me to post another way but they say I can't post this way. So if you already don't have those please let me know I will try to transfer you another way...

Comment: I don't. You may try to use online sharing services.

Comment: Ok, I placed as a link in the original post, I hope you can see it...

Comment: Today I got a notification for release 2020.2.2. Maybe the issue is fixed.

Comment: I added your pom.xml snippet into my test pom.xml and dependencies were resolved without issues.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to create a Reproducer with the same constellation but it didn't caused the Problem, with my real Project I still have the Problem but I am not able to reproduce the Problem in a seperate project. Is there a way to switch IntelliJ to debug mode, so it will log more to idea.log?

Comment: Have you tried to remove all IDE related data (.iml files and .idea folders) abd reimport project from pom.xml?

Comment: Yep, multiple times...

Comment: Could you please try IDEA 2020.3 EAP (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) with default settings ("File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings")?

Comment: Yep, it works with 2020.2.3, but I still don't know the root cause...

Comment: It might be some corruption in IDE configuration.